# Check if value is in another table and add columns in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 tables, `table1` contains some survey data and `table2` is a full list of students involved. I want to check if `Name` in `table2` is also found in `table1`. If yes, add `Age` and `Level` information in `table2`, otherwise, fill these columns with `no data`.

table1:

```
id  Name  Age  Level 
32  Anne  13   Secondary school 
35  Jimmy 5    Primary school
38  Becky 10   Primary school
40  Anne  13   Secondary school
```

table2:

```
id  Name   
1   Anne   
2   Jimmy    
3   Becky    
4   Jack
```

Expected output:

```
id  Name   Age      Level 
1   Anne   13       Secondary school 
2   Jimmy  5        Primary school
3   Becky  10       Primary school
4   Jack   no data  no data
```

Update:

I created a relationship between `table1` and `table2` using the common column `id`(which can be repeated in `table1`).

Then I used:

```
Column = RELATED(table1[AGE])
```

but it caught error:

```
The column 'table1[AGE]' either doesn't exist or doesn't have a relationship to any table available in the current context.
```

Comment: Create a relationship using `Name` please because names are common between those two tables not the `ID` column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to achieve the desired output, but the simplest of them I found is to use the `RELATED` DAX function. If you found this answer then mark it as the answer.

1. Create a relationship between `table1` and `table2` using 'Name` column.

[image: Two Tables]

2. Create a calculated column  in `table2` as:

   `Column = RELATED(table1[AGE])`
3. Repeat the same step for the `Level` column also.

   `Column 2 = RELATED(table1[LEVEL])`

This will give you a table with `ID`, `Name`, `Age`, and `Level` for the common names between the two tables.

[image: Table2]

3. Now to fill those empty rows as `no data`, simply create another calculated column with following DAX:

   `Column 3 = IF(ISBLANK(table2[Column]), "no data", table2[Column])`

   `Column 4 = IF(ISBLANK(table2[Column 2]), "no data", table2[Column 2])`
4. This will give you the desired output.

[image: Final Output]

**EDIT:-** You can also use the following formula to do the same thing in a single column

```
     Column = 
     VAR X = RELATED(table`[AGE])
     VAR RES = IF(ISBLANK(X), "no data", X)

     RETURN
         RES
```

and

```
    Column 2 = 
    VAR X = RELATED(table1[LEVEL])
    VAR RES = IF(ISBLANK(X), "no data", X)

    RETURN 
       RES
```

This will also give you the same output.

[image: Same O/P different method]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, could you please briefly explain DAX in Step 3? Also, `table1` contains repeated `Name` such as `Anne`, in that case can I still use `Column = RELATED(table1[AGE])`?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Step 3 DAX is checking if the column(calculated column) is blank or not., if it is blank then it will return `no data` otherwise it will return the column value. Please check edit, I have consolidated both of these steps in a single step. If it is not clear then just let me know I will explain it further. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but incurred some error, please see question update for details.

Comment: Please create a relationship using the 'Name` column.

Comment: Hi, sorry I realised that I have overlooked something - the same person might have 2 `Level` values. For instance, Anne might have multiple rows with `Primary school` and `Secondary school` values. Is there a way to get all rows with distinct values in `Level`?